# Get all <em> from a <p> and output them like a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

for example i have a `<p>` tag which contain some sentences with `<em>` like below

```
    <p>There's <em>a</em> script that he's 
     written that is <em>a</em> really cool Batman idea.</p>
```

and I use some javascript to add a class to all em element

```
 $("em").addClass("Keyword-Result");
```

And now i'd like to know how am i able to print out all `<em class="Keyword-Result")` like tags?

[image]

Comment: `to print out` What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @anson920520 Please check the updated answer. I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Erm, not sure what you're asking exactly. Are you asking how to style the `em`'s with their new classes? In which case it would simply be: `em.Keyword-Result {}`

Answer (score 1):

However there's no need to add class dynamically here but here is snippet which also appends tags to #tags:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p>There's <em>a</em> script that he's 
     written that is <em>a</em> really cool Batman idea.</p>

<div id="tags"></div>

    <style>
   em.Keyword-Result {
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 4px;
    border-radius: 2px;
     margin:2px;
     color:#fff;
    }
    </style>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
  $("em").clone().addClass("Keyword-Result").appendTo('#tags');
   
     });

    </script>
```

Comment: There is no need for each loop here

Comment: Yeah, if you can clone and append them all to #tags without looping.

Comment: You really don't need a loop, jQuery does that for you, see the second fiddle in my answer below.

Comment: Right, but it I chose to loop to demonstrate individual access to selected tags. However, just simplified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way:

```
console.log($("em.Keyword-Result"));
```

But you don't want to print it in the console but rather on screen? Then you don't need to print them (they are already there) but use css to format them.

```
<style>
em.Keyword-Result {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
</style>
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/d2xrrukh/

Or, if you want to copy the em's to a separate div without needing a loop:

https://jsfiddle.net/d2xrrukh/3/